# Can enough cross-sectional data eventually substitute for longitudinal studies?

Tags: probability, distributions, panel-data, cross-section

Imagine there is an injection being recommended, and it’s to lower your risk of getting a disease. The injection is new, meaning almost no time has passed to do a proper longitudinal study on its efficacy, and more importantly its safety.

While there are no long-term data available, there is a massive sample size of individuals who have taken the injection. This effectively represents a large cross-sectional dataset of injection information.

The question is, can that cross-sectional dataset, which normally would not substitute for longitudinal data, now substitute for longitudinal data because of its massive sample size?

Is there something in the statistical arsenal, specifically probability, that would reveal chronic symptoms surfacing as acute symptoms for a small but significant portion of the population (the tail of some distribution) if the sample size is large enough?

Comment: No, there’s no magic.

Comment: @Aksakal Not an answer, try harder.

Comment: It’s a comment not an answer. You know the answer yourself

Comment: @Aksakal https://twitter.com/nntaleb/status/1644604880642793473?s=46&t=A-eYEbASKYlgtbwPNGnZuw

Comment: smoking is actually a good example. making 6K people smoke 1M cigarettes is not the same as making 6B people smoke one cigarette each. in the latter there will not be any effect on cancer, in the former you should get a pretty good effect.

Comment: @Aksakal no, you are not understanding. The argument being made (by the world’s top probabilist) is that a large enough sample will show long-term damage in the tails of the distribution. This has to do with Poisson processes, dynamics with memory and error propagation. If you don’t understand probability then let someone else chime in. You have to be very good at statistics and probability for this discussion.

Comment: 1. you can't really strengthen the argument by saying "Taleb said it" not only because he's often controversial, but also because this only works on general public not among experts. to me his opinion is as good as of any top rated user in this forum. 2. his argument is ergodicity. it's actually a very useful assumption that is used all the time, but it is pretty much impossible to prove. in my view smoking is a good case where it doesn't work. generally, in cases where statistics substitutes intrinsic understanding of the phenomenon, ergodicity doesn't work.

Comment: @Aksakal "only works on general public not among experts" is itself an argument from authority and thus logically fallacious. As for my argument, you dismissed the question outright ("you know the answer yourself") which is ridiculous if a leading probabilist has the opposite view of yours. Ergodicity is one way to frame it, but there are ways to rigorously argue whether a system is, or is not, ergodic. Your baseline assumption that it is not is unfounded. This is obviously a worthwhile question to ask, esp. considering no statistician seems up to the task. It's also immnsly socially imprtant.